# Xcode does not detect tesseract and opencv headers

Tags: xcode, macos, opencv, ocr, tesseract

I am trying to compile a C++ project that uses OpenCV and Tesseract(not iOS) in Xcode 5.1. I have downloaded OpenCV and Tesseract and the header and library files are sitting in my /usr/local/include/ and /usr/local/lib/ folders respectively.

I have tried modifying my Xcode project "Header search paths" and "Library search paths" to include the above two folders according to [this](https://gist.github.com/balazspete/6982565).

However, I am getting the following compilation errors in round robin fashion 
"Lexical Preprocessor Issue - 'tesseract\baseapi.h' file not found"
"Lexical Preprocessor Issue - 'opencv\cv.h' file not found"

I have also tried adding specific paths for tesseract and opencv with no luck.

Has anyone fixed this issue before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was fixed when the libraries were added to the Xcode project. Refer to https://gist.github.com/balazspete/6982565